# Test functions ineffective

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm using a promise to wait on a Facebook API response in the middle of a Mocha test. I'm wondering why the `expect` function is not actually checking that the data is included in the response.

I see `resolve` in the console, suggesting the graph call worked and the promise resolved, but the test passes, even though the event does not include the random data in the `expect(data).to.include` statement. How can I get test the response when the promise resolves?

```
 var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 var eventFB1 = graph.get('132166232459578/posts',
   {limit: 1,
     access_token: 't0k3n'
   });

  if (typeof eventFB1 !== 'undefined') {
    resolve(eventFB1);
    console.log('resolve');
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
    console.log('reject');

  }
  });

  return promise.then(function(data) {
    expect(data).to.include( 'Event name: Testing London eveng 23498723rstni' );
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation.

Comment: A lot of things are covered in docs but are not obvious to everyone so they seek support here. Is that not a valid approach? Interestingly, the answer that turns out to work for me (below) seems to be described as erroneous by the docs: http://mochajs.org "In Mocha v3.0.0 and newer, returning a Promise and calling done() will result in an exception, as this is generally a mistake:"

Comment: I'm not trying to be insulting, but 'asynchronous code' is the **fourth entry in the documentations table of contents**. Its just below the fold on the homepage. The most cursory inspection of the docs should have caught that. Not to mention all of the excellent stuff that pops up if you google 'mocha async test'. I've asked here about obvious stuff at times too, but at least have the grace to say 'oops, my bad'.

Comment: Not taking it as an an insult, just saying that I had looked through docs and found a statement (beneath that which you note) which appeared to suit my use case (i.e. `promises`) and warned against using `done()`. Surely you can see my confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in done as an argument to your test and then call it in your "then" method.  The done argument tells mocha that the specified test is finished.

```
it('should have the included string for data', (done) => { // <-- add done as argument
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var eventFB1 = graph.get('132166232459578/posts',
    {
      limit: 1,
      access_token: 't0k3n'
    });

    if (typeof eventFB1 !== 'undefined') {
      resolve(eventFB1);
      console.log('resolve');
    }
    else {
      reject(Error("It broke"));
      console.log('reject');
    }
  });

  return promise
    .then(function(data) {
      expect(data).to.include( 'Event name: Testing London eveng 23498723rstni' );
      console.log(data);
      done(); // <-- call done 
    });
}
```

If your test throws an error and done is not called in the catch block, your test will hang and time out after 2 seconds.

Comment: Not sure why I got a vote down for this answer.  ::shrugs::